# Show that $\frac{\sin\left(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)}{\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}=\frac{a+b}{c}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In a triangle $ABC$, with $AB=c,BC=a,AC=b$ and $\measuredangle ABC=\beta,\measuredangle ACB=\gamma,\measuredangle BAC=\alpha$, show that $$\dfrac{\sin\left(\beta+\dfrac{\gamma}{2}\right)}{\sin\dfrac{\gamma}{2}}=\dfrac{a+b}{c}$$

[image]

In the expression that we are supposed to prove we have angle $\dfrac{\gamma}{2}$ two times, so I decided to construct the angle bisector of $\measuredangle ACB:CL$. Using $\sin(180^\circ-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$ $$\sin\measuredangle BLC=\sin\left[180^\circ-\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{2}+\beta\right)\right]=\sin\left(\dfrac{\gamma}{2}+\beta\right)$$

What can we do next? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This identity (after some slight trigonometry fiddling) is apparently well-known enough to have a name - [Mollweide's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide%27s_formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motivation for drawing the angle bisector is easily evident as after construction of the angle bisector we've the triangle ALC which has angles $\frac{\gamma}{2}$ and $\left(\beta +\frac{\gamma}{2} \right)$ , where we can use the law of sines to get
$$\dfrac{\sin\left(\beta+\dfrac{\gamma}{2}\right)}{\sin\dfrac{\gamma}{2}}=\frac{b}{AL}$$

Then using Angle bisector theorem we can compute $AL=\frac{bc}{a+b}$

Using this we get the desired answer

Answer (score 4):

Here's a trigonographic demonstration:

[image]

$$c\,\sin\left(\beta+\frac\gamma2\right) = a\,\sin\frac\gamma2+b\,\sin\frac\gamma2=(a+b)\sin\frac\gamma2$$

Answer (score 1):

By sine rule, In $\triangle CAL$

$\displaystyle\frac{\sin(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{2})}{b}=\frac{\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}{AL}$

By sine rule, In $\triangle CBL$

$\displaystyle\frac{\sin(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{2})}{a}=\frac{\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}{BL}$

Taking reciprocal of above two equations and then adding them gives

$\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{\sin(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{2})}=\frac{AL+BL}{sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}$

$\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{\sin(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{2})}=\frac{c}{sin\frac{\gamma}{2}}$

which is the required result.